# Нужно изменить этот код с помощью switch case

Tags: java, arraylist, switch

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <String> toDoList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Введите команду (Add (№) дело, delete №, edit № дело, list).");
        while(true){

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str = scanner.nextLine();

            String [] words = str.split("\\s");
            if (words.length == 1){
                for (int i = 0; i < toDoList.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println(i + " " + toDoList.get(i));
                }
            }

            else{
                String index = words[1].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                String item = str.substring(str.indexOf(' ')).trim();

                if (words.length == 2) {
                    if (words[0].equalsIgnoreCase("DELETE")){
                        int indexValue = Integer.parseInt(index);

                        if (indexValue >= toDoList.size()){
                            System.out.println("Номер дела введён неверно!");
                        }
                        else {
                            toDoList.remove(indexValue);
                        }
                    }

                    else if(words[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")){
                        toDoList.add(item);
                    }
                }

                else if (words.length > 2){
                    String itemWOIndex = item.substring(item.indexOf(' ')).trim();

                    if (index.isEmpty()){
                        toDoList.add(item);
                    }

                    else {
                        int indexValue = Integer.parseInt(index);

                        if (words[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")){
                            if (indexValue >= toDoList.size()){
                                toDoList.add(itemWOIndex);
                            }
                            else if (indexValue < toDoList.size()) {
                                toDoList.add(indexValue, itemWOIndex);
                            }
                            else{
                                toDoList.add(item);
                            }
                        }

                        else if (words[0].equalsIgnoreCase("EDIT")){
                            if (indexValue > toDoList.size()){
                                System.out.println("Номер дела введён неверно!");}
                            else {
                                toDoList.remove(indexValue);
                                toDoList.add(indexValue, itemWOIndex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: И что вы сделали, что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Ну как минимум когда пыталась совместить условия проверки из этого кода со своим то запуталась, ибо эта тема для меня новая. Поэтому оставила тут вопрос, чтобы понять логику как занести то что есть в код с использованием switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch(words.length) {
  case 0:
    break;
  case 1:
    ...
    break;
  case 2:
    ...
    break;
  default:
    ...
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно поняла то главное условие я пишу в switch, а ниже в этом же кейсе выполняю проверки через if?

Comment: @Lina Например, вместо `...` между `case 2:` и `break;` надо написать то, что у Вас под условием `if (words.length == 2) {`.